# How to compare two list based on elements it contains?

Tags: java, list, collections, compare

In my unit test class, I am having two list. One is the `expectedValue` and other is `returnedType`.

I am doing

```
Collections.sort(expected);
Collections.sort(returned);
```

but how do I compare two list based on the type of value of one of its element? For example I have element `sortOrder` in both the list and it has values from `1,2 or 3` so how do i compare or say doing something like `assertEqual(expected, returned) for both the list` and make sure that both list has same elements and has same sortOrder meanings elements are also in proper sort format?

**Note:** I should not be using any external libraries for doing it.

**Update**

Example of my return and expected list:

`excepted List = [Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2, Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1]` and 
`returned List = [Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1, Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2]`

So at very basic question here is how can I sort a list based on one of its element value, in our example according to `sortOrder` value so our expected should be

`excepted List = [Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1, Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2]`

Comment: Description of the problem is very unclear.  You can't sort a collection based on the value of one of the elements -- sorting a collection sorts all of the values that it contains.  And you can very easily test whether two lists contain the same values in the same order by using list1.equals(list2).

Comment: @JimN: List collection can be sorted based upon one of its element's value and this can be done using comparator

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "element" and what you mean by "value".

Comment: in the list above `element` refers to `sortOrder` and `values` refers to value of sortOrder i.e, 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Best way is to do

```
assertEquals(expected, returned);
```

because AbstractList implements equals using pairwise comparison.
If you are not sure, the Lists you are receiving inherit from AbstractList, you can always do

```
assertEquals(new ArrayList(expected), new ArrayList(returned));
```

I leave the rest of the answer for documentary purposes (and to not hide my shameful ignorance)

Do you want to assert that the lists are in the correct order also?

```java
public static void assertEquals(List expected, List returned)
{
    assertEquals(expected.size(), returned.size());
    if(!expected.containsAll(returned))
    {
       fail();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++)
    {
        assertEquals(expected.get(i),returned.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I need to assert that both list have same elements and both list's elements are in same order

Comment: I am using Junit test framework and so need to have simple assert Method

Comment: hwo can i compare two list based on value of one of it's element?

Comment: From your updated part of the question it is completely unclear what you are trying to achieve. 
What are the elements in your list?

Comment: My return list has [Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1, Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2] elements and  excepted List = [Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2, Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1]

Comment: in your updated code also we are checking for values and not about their order

Comment: @DoubleMalt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1903/discussion-between-rachel-and-doublemalt)

Comment: i am not sure how to explain it but what i am trying to do is sort list based on one of its element value, in this case its `sortOrder`, am i somewhat clear?

Comment: Still seems entirely unnecessary when you can just do exected.equals(returned).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: That won't work. Collections don't implement `equals()`, so the default implementation in `Object` is used, which compares memory addreses - ie `list1.equals(list2)` is the same as `list1 == list2`, which is always false

Comment: `AbstractList` does indeed override `equals()`. `AbstractSequentialList` extends `AbstractList` so it also overrides `equals()`. Every default implementation of `List` in Java 6 overrides `equals()`.

Comment: Oh - sorry about that (I was shooting from the hip - my bad). I'll check out the implementation. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) - library of matchers for building test expressions.

It offers lots of methods to compare Collections (and other hard-to-compare classes) and special matchers that tell you *why* the collections didn't match while throwing AssertionErrors

Comment: is there a way to do it without using any external libraries?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Bohemian's answer (+1), [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) is a very good way to do this.  Here's an example:

```
assertThat(myListOfIntegers, contains(1, 2, 3));
```

`Matchers.contains` asserts that the list elements are the right type, the right quantity, and in the right order.  Therefore, in the above assertion i'm expecting `myListOfIntegers` to be the exact list: `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the objects in the list override the equals and hashcode methods, but otherwise you can just compare the lists directly as per the contract of java.util.List which states that they are equal if the lists contain the same objects in the same order.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:
    CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(expected, returned);