# Sorting list based on its element's value

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

How to sort list based on its element value?

In my unit test class, I am receiving list which is in sorted form based on one of its element's value `{sortOrder and it has value 1, 2 and 3}` now I am comparing `returnedList` with `expectedList` to make sure that both list are same and have same elements in same order.

Example of my return and expected list:

`expected List = [Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2, Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1]`

and `returned List = [Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1, Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2]`

So how can i sort the list on SortOrder so that my expected list becomes:

`expected List = [Code: STREET, SortOrder: 1, Code: ANALYST, SortOrder: 2]`

I cannot use any libraries and this question is related to [Compare List Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6852117/164299), any suggestions?

Comment: Why is it "you can't use libraries"? That sounds unlikely, unless this is "homework", in which case tag it as such. I answered [your other very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852117/how-to-compare-two-list-based-on-elements-it-contains) with "use Hamcrest", and it applies here too.

Comment: @Bohemian: We are using spring framework and doing unit testing via spring and junit and we are not supposed to use any external libraries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this:

```
 public static void sort(List list, Comparator c)
```

So do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(myList, myComparator)
```

myComparator is an interface for which you only have to implement one method which is compare:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
```

So you can do this with an anonymous inner class:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyType>(){ 
    public int compare(MyType o1, MyType o2) { 
        //My implementation
    }
 });
```

For information on how to implement the compare method take a look at the documentation here:

[Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I am doing it for unit testing and so am not sure how to implement `myComparator` in junit testing class

Comment: @Rachel not if you implement it as an anonymous inner class like in my example :)

Comment: so in my case it would be `public int compare(sortOrder returned, sortOrder expected)` ?

Comment: @Rachel No it would be the same method signature, what you have to return is 1, 0 or -1 depending if o1 should be greater equal or less than o2, so the sorting can be done.

Comment: I am still trying to understand, actually i have never implemented comparator before

Comment: @Rachel what will happen inside Collection.sort, is that the API will use the comparator provided, to compare all the objects in your list, then based on the values returned by the compare method, it can sort them, please take a look at the link provided at the end for information on how to implement the compare method

Comment: *"is implementing comparator for unit testing not an overkill"* - it is not overkill.  In fact, it sounds like you've got no real alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to modify the list returned, you have two options:

- If you can modify the object (that you have a list of), implement Comparable and override the compareTo(MyObject) method.
- If you cannot modify the object, then create a Comparator and pass it to your sort method.

If you cannot modify the list, do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
newList.addAll(reterunedList);
newList.removeAll(expectedList);
// check here (newList.size() > 0 ?)
expectedList.removeAll(returnedList);
// check here (expectedList.size() > 0 ?)
```

If there is anything left in the lists in either of those two checks it means your lists are different. And you haven't modified your returned list. It requires your MyObject to have implemented the equals() method properly.

Comment: can you provide an example, also i cannot modify the list

Comment: I gave you a sample code. For an example on the first part, read Oscar's reply.

Comment: *"also i cannot modify the list"* - well copy it, and sort the copy.